# To populate Database tables into JavaFX Tables with 1000s of rows

Tags: java, mysql, javafx-2

There are many similar questions like this But this one is slightly different.

I am developing an JavaFX application. I have mysql database in my application. I have around 2500 tables and each tables will have around 1000 rows. I want to display these table rows in the JavaFX when user selects the table name.

I have gone through various post regarding this, But in most of the cases, they created the class which holds the data of the table  `(POJO)` and then populate in the `TableView` using `Controller`.

How Can I manage this amount of data in JavaFX as making 2500 of classes in not at all practical?

If I create object for every row, so at the end there will be around 1000 or more of object, So i think it will cause outofmemory error on system will low memory.

Does anybody have any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> How Can I manage this amount of data in JavaFX as making 2500 of
>   classes in not at all practical?

Use something general, such as `String[]` as the data type for the table. There's an example similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436196/populating-tableview-with-data-from-database-failed-to-set-rows).

> If I create object for every row, so at the end there will be around
>   1000 or more of object, So i think it will cause outofmemory error on
>   system will low memory.

Not at all. If you have, say, 20 columns in your table, and each value is represented by a `String`, for example, of 100 bytes, then each object in the table is approximately 2KB. (This is all pretty generous; and using your own class as the object type instead of `String[]` adds no appreciable memory consumption.) 1000 rows then takes around 2MB. On most systems, you're likely to have hundreds of MB, or more, available to the JVM.