# Dynamic TableView populating.Error-"duplicate children added".When adding rows from database.Works with single row,fail multiple

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview, rows

I have controller that enable showing result from database in tableView.Problem that i have it **only works with single row data**.If i execute query that have result set which include **multiple rows it fails to populate table**.

Error that i get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = TableRow@7575a6e7[styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]'null'
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:458)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:115)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:507)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:57)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:217)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:876)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8732)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:8725)
    at javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:8825)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:8746)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1799)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1689)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1714)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2305)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1094)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1076)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2386)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:322)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:320)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:320)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:479)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:460)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$13.run(QuantumToolkit.java:327)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Code for populating table:

```
  private void populateTable() {
            for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < dataRows.size(); rowNumber++) {
                for (TableColumn tc : columns) {
                    tc.setCellValueFactory(new ValueFactory(columns.indexOf(tc), rowNumber));
                    dpcontroller.tableView.getColumns().add(tc);
                }
            }
         //data included in dataRows are correct.//after printout debug


         dpcontroller.tableView.setItems(dataRows);//ERROR THROWN  IF MULTIPLE ROWS

        }
```

DataRows is   `private ObservableList<String[]> dataRows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

String[0] represents first row..String[1] second.. etc

Im not sure what is causing this.My guess its that i try to apply second row into first row of table?I have no idea how to fix this. This question is related to my previous question [Populating TableView with data from database.Failed to set rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436196/populating-tableview-with-data-from-database-failed-to-set-rows) Where i tought i fixed problem, bud only partly.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You're adding the columns too many times: you're adding every column once for every row of data you have. And presumably when you say "`String[0]` represents first *row*" you really mean "`String[0] represents first *column*"?

Comment: @James_D dataRows.get(0) <-- first row array. dataRows.get(0)[0] first column of that row.You are correct i put boolen check in place on / dpcontroller.tableView.getColumns().add(tc);/ and everything works.Im really glad you made me notice it!If you post it as an answer i will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't post a complete answer as you didn't post the implementation of your `ValueFactory` class (and I don't really see any reason it needs a reference to the row index). However, you are adding columns too many times: each column is added once for each row of the table. You only need to add the columns once.

You can probably just eliminate the outer `for` loop in the first part of the `populateTable` method:

```
private void populateTable() {
    for (TableColumn tc : columns) {
        // need to figure out how to remove rowNumber from this....
        tc.setCellValueFactory(new ValueFactory(columns.indexOf(tc), rowNumber));
        dpcontroller.tableView.getColumns().add(tc);
    }
    //data included in dataRows are correct.//after printout debug


    dpcontroller.tableView.setItems(dataRows);//ERROR THROWN  IF MULTIPLE ROWS

}
```